# Spark udf for reading unconventional date formats

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Let's say I have an unconventional dates in my spark dataframe:

```
val df = Seq("24-12-2017","25-01-2016").toDF("dates")
df.show()
+----------+
|     dates|
+----------+
|24-12-2017|
|25-01-2016|
```

Then I want to parse these dates to Timestamps and it does not work:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
def fmt(d:String) = {
    val f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
    f.parse(d)
}
val reFormat = udf(fmt(_:String):Timestamp)
cmd15.sc:1: not found: type Timestamp
val reFormat = udf{fmt(_:String):Timestamp}
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is simply due to the fact that `java.sql.Timestamp` is not imported. Yet, importing it would simply lead to a different issue:

> ```
> error: type mismatch;
> found   : java.util.Date
> required: java.sql.Timestamp
> ```

To fix that, you simply need to create a `java.sql.Timestamp` in your UDF:

```
def fmt(d:String) = {
    val ts = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(d).getTime
    new java.sql.Timestamp(ts)
}
val reFormat = udf(fmt(_:String):java.sql.Timestamp)

df.select('dates, reFormat('dates)).show
+----------+-------------------+
|     dates|         UDF(dates)|
+----------+-------------------+
|24-12-2017|2017-12-24 00:00:00|
|25-01-2016|2016-01-25 00:00:00|
+----------+-------------------+
```

That fixes your UDF, but note that there is a function in the SparkSQL API that does exactly what you want:

```
df.select('dates, to_timestamp('dates, "dd-MM-yyyy")).show
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|     dates|to_timestamp(`dates`, 'dd-MM-yyyy')|
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|24-12-2017|                2017-12-24 00:00:00|
|25-01-2016|                2016-01-25 00:00:00|
+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Because I wanted a udf. If you see a simply route employing udf -- you're welcome!